# Exchange 2007 licenses not showing correctly

Tags: exchange-2007, licensing, exchange

We've got our Exchange 2007 environment setup and working correctly.  There is one strange thing however.  When I log onto a mailbox server it tells me that one of the edge transports is in trial mode.  However when I log onto that edge transport server it says that it is correctly licensed.

Which server is correct, and how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the last time the mailbox server "heard" from the ET, it was in trial mode.  Now that the ET is locked down more thoroughly, the mailbox isn't getting updates.  (just a guesss, again)

If you head to the HT and do a:

> get-ExchangeServer | select name,ProductID,*trial* | fl

And receive a:

```
Name                              : SERVERNAME
ProductID                         : [bla bla bla]
IsExchange2007TrialEdition        : False
IsExpiredExchange2007TrialEdition : False
RemainingTrialPeriod              : 00:00:00
```

I'm thinking all is well.  The leftover on the Mailbox server **should** just be informational.  Of course it's Microsoft, so I can understand some apprehension...

Comment: ok, when I run that from an HT the productId for the server in question is blank as is the trial value.  Any how I can do a resync of the data manually (short of reinstalling). I really don't want to have to reconfigure all the spam settings on the edge.

Comment: I wish I knew what a blank result meant.  :/  Is it possible to re-activate with the same code?  Maybe something borked during activation.

Comment: It won't let me put the registration code in again, because I would have to enter the code on the edge server, but the edge says that it has a key.